# How can we evaluate this with Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_0^1\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+(1-nx)^2}dx$$
shall we add and remove$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_0^1\dfrac{x^2+(1-nx)^2-(1-nx)^2}{x^2+(1-nx)^2}dx$$ and going this way
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_0^11-\dfrac{(1-nx)^2}{x^2+(1-nx)^2}dx$$

Comment: No, let the integrand as is. Find a dominating function and take the pointwise limit.

Comment: what about this: $$
f_n(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+(1-nx)^2}\leq\frac{1}{x^2+(1-nx)^2}\leq\frac{1}{x^2}=f(x)
$$ in [0,1]

Comment: $\frac{1}{x^2}$ isn't integrable at $0$. You need a different dominating function.

Comment: The dominating function has to be integrable, which $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is not @kaya_. Do not remove the $x^2$ from the numerator, just remove the $(1-nx)^2$ and you will dominate $f_n$ with 1, which _is_ integrable, and allows you to swap integral and limit by the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: for 1 is a constant that I couldnt be sure about it. but it seems right.

Comment: Btw @kaya_, a similar argument shows the subtracted term in your rewriting of the integral (the way you rewrote it in the post) has an integral which tends to 1 -- try it and comment on the answer to tell me if you managed it :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Theorem (Dominated Convergence)**

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space and $f_n:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be a succession of functions all measurable with respect to $\Sigma$ and the real [Borel sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set). If $f_n\to f$ pointwise (or pointwise almost everywhere) and $|f_n|\leq g$ and $|f|\leq g$ -- or both of these hold almost everywhere --, where $g$ is an integrable function $g:X\to\mathbb{R}$, then:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Xf_n\mathrm{d}\mu=\int_Xf\mathrm{d}\mu.$$

**Proof**

[See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Proof_of_the_theorem).

**Application to our case**

In our case, $(X,\Sigma,\mu)=([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1]),\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. We know that if both the Riemann Integral and the Integral with respect to $\lambda$ exist, then they are equal. We have to evaluate the LHS of the theorem's equality. We have:
$$f_n(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+(1-nx)^2}.$$
Let's try to find that $g$:
$$|f_n(x)|\leq\frac{x^2}{x^2}=1,$$
and $1$ is integrable, so our $g(x)=1$ for all $x\in X$. By the above theorem, the limit passes under the integral, so we now need the pointwise limit of $f_n$.
$$\begin{align*}
f_n(x)={}&\frac{x^2}{x^2+(1-nx)^2}=\frac{x^2}{x^2+n^2x^2-2nx+1}=\frac{x^2}{(n^2+1)x^2-2nx+1}\sim{} \\
{}\sim{}&\frac{x^2}{(1+n^2)x^2}=\frac{1}{n^2+1}\to0.
\end{align*}$$
So the pointwise limit -- the $f$ in the above theorem -- is 0, meaning the limit we have to evaluate is 0.

**Exercise**

Use the Dominated Convergence Theorem in a similar way to establish that the subtracted term in your way of rewriting the integral in the question has an integral tending to 1.

Comment: (+1) but just mentioning that $\frac{x^2}{x^2+(1-nx)^2}\le1$ and on $[0,1]$, $1$ is an integrable function would allow us to use Dominated Convergence. The rest is correct, but might distract from the main point.

Comment: @robjohn What "rest"? The statement of the theorem? I think one needs to know the statement of a theorem before applying it. The fact that the pointwise limit is 0? But the question says «How can we evaluate», so we need the pointwise limit. The exercise? Well I don't see how _that_ could distract. So what are you criticizing? I genuinely cannot see…

Comment: Anyways thx for the +1 :).

Answer (score 4):

For all $n$,
$$x^2+(1-nx)\geq x^2\implies \frac{x^2}{x^2+(1-nx)^2}\leq 1\in L^1(0,1)$$

therefore you can permute limit and integral and you finally find 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty }\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{x^2+(1-nx)^2}dx=\int_0^1\underbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{x^2}{x^2+(1-nx)^2}}_{=0}dx=0.$$